# "It is" or "it was" in this scenario?

Tags: grammar, tenses

Is the following sentence correct?

> I still remembered that the school manager in the seminar talked really sweetly about how bright future *it is* if a student could finish their courses.

Clearly, the school manager talked in the past.

Do I need to change to *it was*?

> I still remembered that the school manager in the seminar talked really sweetly about how bright future *it was* if a student could finish their courses.

Comment: I would favor "how bright future it *would be* if a student could...". There are other minor errors in your sentence. Maybe *still remember* or just *remembered* depending on what you're trying to say. Have you looked at [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: **Was** is marginally preferable as it is reported speech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an awkward sentence, and the meaning is unclear.  What really struck me is the use of *student*, which is singular and *their*, which is plural.  Also, I wonder about the words, *how bright future it is*...       Addressing these two issues and the original matter of tense, I might rewrite it in the following way...

> I still remembered *when* the school manager in the seminar *spoke* (omit really) sweetly about *how bright* the future would be if a student could finish *his or her* courses.

Sometimes the whole *his or her* thing sounds clunky, so if it makes sense in the context of what is being written, maybe it could be....

> I still remembered *how* the school manager in the seminar spoke sweetly about how bright the future would be if *the students could finish their* courses.

Finally, unless the following would be changing the meaning too much, the clearest version....

> *I remembered* how the school manager in the seminar spoke sweetly about *a brighter future if only the students finished their courses*.

(Note:  in the final version, I removed the word "still," yet it may belong if it is relevant to the author's meaning.)

Comment: "They" has been used as a singular pronoun for a very long time, and I've never heard of anyone being confused by this usage (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_they). Although some people frown upon the singular "they," others prefer it to the clunky "her or his."

Comment: Vectornaut, I agree, the use of his/her is awkward, yet resorting to the singular they is not ideal either, despite the fact it is more accepted. Fortunately, there is a 3rd option, which is why I suggested making both the pronoun and the antecedent plural, unless there is only 1 student which would change the author's meaning. Also, just to clarify,the usage of a singular they was not why I found the sentence a bit confusing, but looking over my comment I see how one might come to that conclusion. It was the "how bright future" word choice. New to this, sorry if I offended anyone.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For me, different choices of tense can convey subtly different meanings. For example, I sometimes use the present tense if the speaker was describing a condition which is still ongoing:

- "Yesterday, Coach Wu told us we *have* a good chance of winning the playoffs."
- "The doctor called last night and said my uncle *is* feeling better."
- "In the 16th century, Copernicus described a universe in which the sun *is* fixed and the planets *revolve* around it."

On the other hand, I might use the past tense to suggest that the speaker was describing a condition which is no longer true:

- "Yesterday, Coach Wu told us we *had* a good chance of winning the playoffs. That was before our goalie broke her ankle."
- "The doctor called last night and said my uncle *was* feeling better. When I went to visit him this morning, however, he seemed much worse."

I might also use the past tense if the speaker was describing a situation which is now in the past:

- "Last season, Coach Wu told us we *had* a good chance of winning the playoffs."
- "In *Les Misérables*, Victor Hugo described a Paris in which the poor *were* struggling to survive."